# What causes "SQL Error [IX000]: Overflow occurred on a datetime or interval operation." and how can I fix it?

Tags: sql, informix

I want to export data resulting from the query below.

```
SELECT id, number, dat1, dat2, (dat1 - dat2)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND::VARCHAR(10)::INTEGER AS dat1_dat2
FROM informix.table_ 
WHERE departement=='NY'
AND dat1 >='2021-03-01 00:00:00' 
AND dat1 <'2021-08-01 00:00:00'
AND ((dat1 - dat2)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND::VARCHAR(10)::INTEGER > -60 
AND (dat1 - dat2)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND::VARCHAR(10)::INTEGER<60) 
AND ((dat2 - dat1)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND::VARCHAR(10)::INTEGER > -60 
AND (dat2 - dat1)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND::VARCHAR(10)::INTEGER<60)
```

I get the error below. Does anyone knows why I can't export my data ?

> Task execution failed
>
> Motif:
> SQL Error [IX000]: Overflow occurred on a datetime or interval operation.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data — specifically, sample values for `dat1` and `dat2` columns.  Unless your times are many years apart, you should not be running into problems.  An interval with 9 digits fits happily into an INTEGER (when you go through the necessary conversion to string as an intermediary).

Comment: The error number is -1265: Overflow occurred on a datetime or interval operation.  The explanation says: _Both DATETIME and INTERVAL values are stored internally as DECIMAL values. In this statement, an arithmetic operation that uses DATETIME and/or INTERVAL values has caused an arithmetic overflow. This situation should not occur. Check the precision that is specified for an INTERVAL value. If the INTERVAL value that you want to enter is greater than the default number of digits that are allowed for that field, you must explicitly identify the number of significant digits in your definition._

Comment: how should i change my query please? thank you ?? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: I don’t yet know what your data is so I can’t yet tell where it is going wrong.  The error explanation hints that you shouldn't be seeing the information.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler example of row: 3232, 200, 2021-07-31 23:59:44, 2021-08-03,  23:59:43

Comment: Thanks — that was timely; I was just about to start trying to reproduce with my own data.

Comment: thank you ^^other row: 7748, 41, 2021-07-01 13:00:00, 2021-07-02 13:00:00

Comment: Can you say which version of Informix you're using, and which platform (o/s and version) you're using it on? You don't include `departement` in your sample data;  I just dropped that condition. Testing with 12.10.FC6 on a Mac running macOS X 10.14.6 (antique — we can discuss another time), I don't see an error.  Ditto on a Linux machine (RHEL 7.4) running Informix 14.10.FC7. I can send my repro script to you if. you contact me by email — see my profile (please include SO 6945-1047 in the subject). You can then hack it to make it reproduce on your system. I might add that no data is selected.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce it with a data row: `INSERT INTO overflow VALUES(3234, 202, '2021-07-31 23:59:44', '1981-08-01 00:00:13');` (I renamed the table to `overflow`).  The difference between the two dates is more than 1,000,000,000 seconds, so the value doesn't fit into INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND.

Comment: Try doing `SELECT id, number, dat1, dat2, (dat1 -  dat2) AS dat1_dat2 FROM overflow WHERE (dat1 - dat2) > INTERVAL(11574 00:00:00) DAY(5) TO SECOND`.  There are 999993600 seconds in 11574 days; any bigger difference is. likely to cause the overflow.  With the data shown before, the difference is `14609 23:59:31`, which comfortably exceeds the limit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler got this error SQL Error [IX000]: Overflow occurred on a datetime or interval operation.

Comment: You shouldn’t get the overflow error if you do no casting.

Comment: i did it exactly as you mentioned ... @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Weird!  When I add the row `INSERT INTO overflow VALUES(9999, 999, '9999-12-31 23:59:59', '0001-01-01 00:00:00');` to the table I've been using, the statement `SELECT id, number, dat1, dat2, (dat1 -  dat2) AS dat1_dat2
  FROM overflow
 WHERE (dat1 - dat2) > INTERVAL(11574 00:00:00) DAY(5) TO SECOND;` produces the output `9999|999|9999-12-31 23:59:59|0001-01-01 00:00:00|3652058 23:59:59` (and the difference column is of type `INTERVAL DAY(8) TO SECOND`).  I'm using my SQLCMD program, but DB-Access produces the equivalent result.

Comment: This is going to be best handled off SO — please contact me by email as previously suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an Informix user, but as a developer I can tell you that an overflow error occurs when the result of an operation is too large to fit into a data type. As something to explore, could the result of the operation `(dat1 - dat2)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND::VARCHAR(10)::INTEGER` be too large for an `INTEGER`? It looks like a quick Google search shows that the maximum value for an `INTEGER` in Informix is `2,147,483,647` - is it possible that the number of seconds between `dat1` and `dat2` is larger than this value (that would be more than 68 years)?

So I can't tell you exactly which piece of your query is failing since I cannot see the data, but I can tell you that the result of one of your operations is a very large number that doesn't fit inside of an `INTEGER`, which is -2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647.

In your query, either one of these could be the culprit:

`(dat1 - dat2)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND::VARCHAR(10)::INTEGER`

`(dat2 - dat1)::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND::VARCHAR(10)::INTEGER`

Comment: In fact, the overflow occurs when the difference is larger than 999,999,999 seconds, as INTERVAL SECOND(9) to SECOND is limited to 9 digits.  Increasing the `9` isn't an option — so the problem occurs when the difference is much more than 11574 days (999993600 seconds).